# Markov Property for time Homogenous diffusion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, markov-process

I am reading Affine Diffusions and Related Processes: Simulation, Theory and Applications of Alfonsi, at some point (Chapter 1.2.2), the author writes [simplified]:

> Given:
> $$
> \mathbb{E}\left[\exp(uX_t^x)\right]=\exp\big(\phi_u(t)+\psi_u(t)x\big)
> $$
> Using Markov property, we have:
> $$
> \mathbb{E}\left[\exp(uX^x_T)\mid F_t\right]=\exp\big(\phi_u(T-t)+\psi_u(T-t)X^x_t\big)
> $$
> Where, $t\in[0,T]$ and $X_0=x$

I want to verify this equality. I know that Markov property says that:
$$
\operatorname{E}[f(X_t)\mid\mathcal{F}_s]=\operatorname{E}[f(X_t)\mid\sigma(X_s)]
$$
But I can't figure out how I can use this to show the previous result.